# Postfix - Allow delivery for my domain but block mail to root@localhost for all but local system

Tags: linux, postfix

I use Postfix as an MTA to receive mail for my domain. Recently I've started to get some mails coming in to root@localhost from external IPs trying to exploit bash. My bash is patched so I should be safe enough, but I'm not comfortable with the idea of anyone being able to send mail to the domain root@localhost from anywhere in the world.

I still need localhost for local system mails so don't want to remove it completely, ideally I'd like to block mail to localhost and localhost.hostname from everywhere unless the mail originates on the local system.

Is this possible? Looking at the documentation it looks like something could be done with either smtpd_relay_restrictions or smtpd_recipient_restrictions but I haven't found a working config yet.

Running Ubuntu server 14.04 with postfix 2.11.0-1

postfix -n output below. I hope it's okay but I've removed details of the FQDNs that I use in the output.

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
config_directory = /etc/postfix
home_mailbox = Maildir/
inet_interfaces = all
mailbox_command = /usr/bin/procmail
mailbox_size_limit = 0
mydestination = <hostname>, <domain>, localhost.<hostname>, mail.<domain>, localhost
myhostname = <hostname>
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
myorigin = /etc/mailname
queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix
readme_directory = no
recipient_delimiter = +
relayhost =
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtpd_use_tls = yes
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
virtual_alias_domains = <virtual_domain_1> <virtual_domain_1> <virtual_domain_2> <virtual_domain_3> <virtual_domain_4>
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
```

Comment: *I haven't found a working config yet* --> Could you post the non-working config so we know how your postfix environment? Providing output of `postconf -n` is very useful to us.

Comment: Thanks masegaloeh output added to original question now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you already have `permit_mynetworks` in `smtpd_relay_restrictions`, then you can add the new restriction after it.

```
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, check_recipient_access hash:/etc/postfix/block_localhost, permit_sasl_authenticated, defer_unauth_destination
```

in `/etc/postfix/block_localhost`, you can put

```
root@localhost REJECT
```

postmap that file and run `postfix reload`.

Mail from local system to *root@localhost* already permitted by `permit_mynetworks`. So, the simple solution is adding rejection of *root@localhost* after it.

Comment: Excellent, just tested that and it works perfectly. Many thanks masegaloeh!